# prove that $Z_1 = i\cot \frac{\theta}{2}$ given that $Z = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> If $Z = \cos \theta+i\sin \theta$, $Z_1= \dfrac{z+1}{z-1}$, prove that $Z_1= -i\cot  \dfrac{θ}{2}\\$

This was a proof that I ran into in a quiz. I couldn't really solve it. I only got as far as $Z_1 = z+1$, $Z_1 = \cos \theta+\sin \theta$ $-1$.

It's bugging me since then. A friend told me we'd prove it using a double angle formula.

Comment: write $Z$ as $e^{i\theta}$ and factor by $e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{z+1}{z-1} &=
  \frac{(\cos \theta+1)+i\sin \theta}{(\cos \theta-1)+i\sin \theta} \\
  &=
  \frac{2\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2}+2i\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}}
       {-2\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}+2i\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}}
  \\ &=
  \cot \frac{\theta}{2}
  \left(
    \frac{\cos \frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin \frac{\theta}{2}}
         {-\sin \frac{\theta}{2}+i\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}
  \right) \\ &=
  \cot \frac{\theta}{2}
    \frac{\cos \frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin \frac{\theta}{2}}
         {i\left(\cos \frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \right)} \\
   &= -i\cot \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: I put a negative in front of the $i$ in the OP